# Facebook API Post Search Alternative

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem regarding the Facebook search post, unfortunately,  post search has been deprecated. The current API version doesn't have a post search. What can I use to search public posts?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, it´s deprecated and there is no way to search public posts now. If it would still be possible then it would be mentioned in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog